# Is Lua an object-oriented language?

Tags: lua

Is this language an OO language?
Is it often used as OO language?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274972/lua-what-is-lua

Comment: To answer your first question, no - but it's OO capable. I don't have enough experience with Lua to answer your second question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lua is fully capable of [prototype-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) object-oriented programming similar to JavaScript.

> Prototype-based programming is a style
>   of object-oriented programming in
>   which classes are not present, and
>   behavior reuse (known as inheritance
>   in class-based languages) is performed
>   via a process of cloning existing
>   objects that serve as prototypes. This
>   model can also be known as class-less,
>   prototype-oriented or instance-based
>   programming. Delegation is the
>   language feature that supports
>   prototype-based programming.

For more information, see [Chapter 16 - Object-Oriented Programming](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html) of the [*Programming in Lua*](http://www.lua.org/pil/) book.

Answer (score 1):

It does support object oriented programming with some difficulty. This chapter in the official guide explains http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html

Answer (score 1):

Lua it's not an OO language "per-se" but offers mechanisms to implement different styles of Object Orientation.

There are a lot of libraries that implement OO for lua. A look at [lua.org](http://www.lua.org) (the main Lua site) or [lua-users](http://lua-users.org) (the Lua Community Wiki) will be helpful.

Even more helpful would be to ask in the Lua Mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

> Lua is a powerful, fast, lightweight,
>   embeddable scripting language.
>
> Lua combines simple **procedural syntax**
>   with powerful data description
>   constructs based on associative arrays
>   and extensible semantics. Lua is
>   dynamically typed, runs by
>   interpreting bytecode for a
>   register-based virtual machine, and
>   has automatic memory management with
>   incremental garbage collection, making
>   it ideal for configuration, scripting,
>   and rapid prototyping.

~ [Lua: about](http://www.lua.org/about.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly used as a scripting tool in Apps, to extend or implement functionalities.