# Is inheritance in Lua prototype-based or class-based?

Tags: class, inheritance, lua, prototype

Lua is often described as having prototype-based inheritance (for example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477732/200783)). However, the ["Inheritance" section](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.2.html) of "Programming in Lua" talks about "base class" and "superclass" - terms from class-based inheritance.

Which model, prototype-based or class-based, best describes how inheritance works in Lua?

Comment: Lua does not have "inheritance" or "classes".  But it is possible to emulate it in Lua.  With a bit of additional work you can treat Lua tables as classes.

Comment: Don't worry about what label to stick on it. Just learn the actual mechanics of how metatables work. Sticking one label or the other on it isn't going to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lua is prototype-based.

Technically, there is no *class* or *inheritance* or *base class*, *super class* in Lua. Lua has some tools like metatables to simulate classical OOP. The main reason that the PiL book uses these terms is to make it easier for the reader to understand.

If you like the language-lawyer way of describing the syntax, read [the reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html), you won't find these terms there.

Answer (score 5):

Lua has a [prototype-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) [inheritance system](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.2.html).  Let's first make sure we understand that Lua doesn't have classes and really every object is of the same type (`table`).  To mimic the notion of a class, lua uses metatables to define a set of properties on the table that are not defined on the table itself.  Two tables can share the same behavior, because we can "prototype" an object with a metatable.

```
table1 = {}
table2 = {}

behavior = {myfunction = function() return 10 end}

setmetatable(table1, behavior)
setmetatable(table2, behavior)

table1.myfunction()   --> 10
table2.myfunction()   --> 10
```

In this way, `table1` and `table2` have the same behaviors and can be thought of as having the same "class", even though we really just defined the same behavior on two different tables.

To create a notion of inheritance, there are many options.  Personally, I like the idea of creating a metatable, and [programmatically merging the fields on the metatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283388/lua-merge-tables) that I'd like to "derive" from.  Then, using this new merged metatable we can set the metatable on our new object.

```
behavior_derived = {myNewFunction = function() return 20 end}

-- merge the base behavior in with our derived behavior
for k,v in pairs(behavior) do behavior_derived[k] = v end

a_derived = {}
b_derived = {}

setmetatable(a_derived, behavior_derived)
setmetatable(b_derived, behavior_derived)

a_derived.myfunction()      --> 10
a_derived.myNewFunction()   --> 20

b_derived.myfunction()      --> 10
b_derived.myNewFunction()   --> 20
```

This is the closest that Lua can get to deriving "class"es from others that I can think of.

Comment: The initial lua code doesn't work (`attempt to call a nil value (field 'myfunction')`) because it's missing `behavior.__index = behavior`. The __index metamethod says where to lookup the missing 'myfunction'.